# What to do to change td width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

http://serafimtsotsonis.com/dates.html

In this page link I want to change the first row so that the whole sentence is stretched out, and "Serafim bla bla bla" doesn't take 3 lines. This is because I had a 33% width restriction.

What can I do, to change that only in that line and the sentence to occupy only one line, like the others down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the empty middel td in the first row, and set the last td in that row to have a colspan of 2. Something like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="line">
      <td>20_January 2013 </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px; ">
                    Serafim Tsotsonis mixtape 24 :00 - 01 :00 @ <a href="http://www.dinamo.fm/" target="_blank">dinamo.fm</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="line">
      <td>11_January 2013 </td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/565108543517894/567425516619530/" target="_blank">Sporos Bar, Athens</a></td>
   </tr>
   ...
```

Or is trhis not what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

use nowrap attribute

```
<td nowrap="nowrap">
```

or with css (better, as nowrap attribute is deprecated in html 4.01 and doesn't exist in html5)

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can use the <colgroup>tag
<colgroup>
<col width="total width of the first column" />
<col width="*" />
</colgroup>
```

Note:  use this if the column has a wide width to take of